# executing variable with eval '$cmd' will generate error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eval, cat

If I save my cat command into a string and then I execute it then I will get an error

```
linux# cmd="cat /data/test/test.tx* | grep toto"
linux# eval '$cmd'
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: toto: No such file or directory
```

even with

```
linux# $cmd
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: toto: No such file or directory
```

I know that

```
linux# eval "$cmd"
```

works, but in my script I want to use `eval '$cmd'`

how to execute the cat command when it's saved into a variable?

Now if the `cmd="echo anymessage"` then

```
linux# eval '$cmd'
linux# $cmd
linux# eval "$cmd"
```

all of them will work

Comment: Is there any test.tx* in /data/test?

Comment: @fedorqui yes there is test.txt file

Comment: `eval` should have worked here.

Comment: @devnull `eval "$cmd"`works  and `eval '$cmd'` does not work

Comment: @MOHAMED Saying either `eval $cmd` or `eval "$cmd"` should work.  `eval '$cmd'` wouldn't work for obvious reasons (single quotes)

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to use single quotes there instead of double ones?

Comment: @devnull `eval '$cmd'` works if the `cmd="echo toto"`

Comment: @MOHAMED `eval '$cmd'` is identical to `$cmd`; you are evaluating a parameter expansion, not the string the parameter expands to.

Comment: @chepner Could you detail your comment into an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a simple command, which works either way, but for different reasons.

```
$ cmd="echo anymessage"
$ eval '$cmd'
```

`eval '$cmd'` has `eval` processing the string `$cmd`. It splits it into words, which is again simply the single word `$cmd`. It expands the parameter to `echo anymessage` and performs one more round of word-splitting to get `echo` and `anymessage`. Now, `echo` is the command and `anymessage` is the argument, and the `echo` command is executed.

```
$ eval "$cmd"
```

Here, `eval` is processing the string `echo anymessage`, because `bash` has performed parameter expansion on `$cmd` *before* executing `eval`. The string is again split into words, with `echo` recognized as the command.

Now, let's use a more complicated value for `cmd`.

```
$ cmd="cat /data/test/test.tx* | grep toto"
$ eval '$cmd'
```

Again, `eval` receives the literal string `$cmd`. That's the entire command line, after word-splitting, so it's a simple command: no pipeline, no redirections, etc. The parameter is expanded to the *single* string `cat /data/test/test.tx* | grep toto`. Next, word splitting produces the words `cat`, `/data/test/test.tx*`, `|`, `grep`, and `toto`. Pathname expansion occurs
on the pattern; let's just say it expands to the single file name `/data/test/test.txt`. You now have 5 words with no more expansions to perform, so the shell identifies the word `cat` in command position, and runs that with the remaining 4 words as arguments. The error occurs when `cat` cannot find files named `|`, `grep`, and `toto`.

Finally, let's use double quotes

```
$ eval "$cmd"
```

This time, `eval` receives the expanded string `cat /data/test/test.tx* | grep toto` as the command line. After word splitting, it sees `cat`, `/data/test/test.tx*`, `|`, `grep`, and `toto`. This multi-word command line contains a pipe character, so `eval` processes it as a pipeline. Compare to the previous example, where `eval`'s single argument only contained a single word `$cmd`. From here, you should be able to see how the pipeline is executed as expected.

---

In summary, you need to use double-quotes on the argument to `eval` if it is a single parameter containing a complex command line that you want to parse and execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the shell to process the pipe normally, not as part of the `cat` command. One way to do so is to pass it a new instance of the shell.

```
sh -c "$cmd"
```

Note that this introduces all sorts of quoting issues, and it is best to not attempt to store shell metacommands in a variable at all.

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake in my question. I updated. Infact the `eval "$cmd"` works

Comment: Still won't save you from the quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Also please note that this code will fail if there are no files in the folder. This is the error that is going to be thrown:

> cat: *: No such file or directory

To fix that you can enable [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)

```
shopt -s nullglob
```